# User is online after token expiration - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt, access-token

I'm using JSON Web Token (JWT) in my Laravel 5.3 API. Now I want to get the online users so, I'm using [highideas/laravel-users-online package](https://packagist.org/packages/highideas/laravel-users-online) and it works with me.

The thing I can't understand is that after a user's token expiration, it still return that he is online for some time after the token expiration!!

Why does this happen ?? and is there any more accurate way to know the online users ?

Comment: Because looking through the source of the package, it only marks users as "offline" when it hears a logout event or the session expires, Token expiration does not fire a logout event.

Comment: Do you suggest any other packages to show online users ? @Joe